# How to get location of a view- swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to track location of a view on drag gesture which belongs to a ZStack. So that I can zoom in or out my view . So what is the best way to get location of a view.

Comment: `DragGesture`'s  `.onChanged` gives you the relative drag coordinates. Isn't that enough?

Comment: no , I want the location when the view is build and drag isnt called yet

Comment: then `GeometryReader` around the view whose coordinates you need

Comment: @meaning-matters ok, then I do :) seemed too easy for a full answer (I'm also still learning the code of conduct here)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your view with a `GeometryReader`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geo in
            
            // frame of YourView in global coordinates
            // gives you minX, minY, widht, height and more
            _ = geo.frame(in: .global)
            
            YourView()
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                            .onChanged({ value in
                    _ = value.translation.width // relative drag x
                    _ = value.translation.height // relative drag y
                })
                )
        }
    }
}
```